# Android Studio Navigation Library problem

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I want to use Navigation in my app.

declared in `main_activity`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Main content -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

then I want to go from Fragment1 to Fragment2 using action
**UPDATE** I am added more code

```
class LoginFragment2 : Fragment(){
    private lateinit var viewModel : LoginViewModel2
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_login, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initViews()

    }

    private fun initViews() {





    btn_registration.setOnClickListener {
//            Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment2_to_newTypeAccountFragment)
//            navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
//            findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment2_to_newTypeAccountFragment)
            this.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment2_to_newTypeAccountFragment)
        }

    }
```

I tried several options (but not one did not help me)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.peshkariki, PID: 22658
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{ca39b84 
V.E...... ........ 0,0-720,1360} does not have a NavController set
```

how to work with it correctly?

**Navigation graph** (In fact, it is very large, but I will post a small part related to this Fragment)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/mainActivity">



        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/loginFragment2"
            android:name="com.app.peshkariki.newPesh.ui.login.LoginFragment2"
            android:label="LoginFragment2"
            tools:layout="@layout/fr_login">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment2_to_newTypeAccountFragment"
                app:destination="@id/newTypeAccountFragment" />
        </fragment>
    </navigation>
```

Comment: Can you share navigation graph ?

Comment: @UpendraShah I can only do the plot, otherwise it is very large

Comment: @UpendraShah update

Comment: `app:startDestination="@id/mainActivity"` Is it correct? or you need to replace it with `app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment2"`

Comment: @asad mahmoodI have a MainActivity will use the Bottom Navigation should be the same as that in the fragments of the primary start? Ok, i am change in app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment2", but error no fade away

Comment: @asadmahmood Ah, you're giving me some strange advice. As if NavHostFragment should be in MainActivity (and it is there), why you try to put it in fragment, I don't know. And what, should I do this in all the fragments?
And Yes, I still tried and the error did not disappear

Answer (score 0):

You called `NavHostFragment` but you don't need to.

Change it to

```kotlin
btn_registration.setOnClickListener {            
    this.findNavController()
        .navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment2_to_newTypeAccountFragment)
}
```

Put this in `onViewCreated`:

```kotlin
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Also you might wanna do this [course](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html#0)

Comment: Can you show more code?  Where are you calling this onClickListener from ?

Comment: why is your `main_activity`(`app:startDestination="@id/mainActivity"`) the destination in your `nav_graph` ?

Comment: @BisShouldn't I? I have a MainActivity will use the Bottom Navigation should be the same as that in the fragments of the primary start?
Ok, i am change in app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment2", but error no fade away